# Delete columns where the minor factors occur only in frequency one or two

Tags: r, matrix

I have following matrix with different strings in each column. The minimum number of different strings in one column is 2. Some columns have up to 20 different strings, some columns have only two different strings. I would like to delete columns where the minor factors occur only in very low frequency (<=2). So columns where one factor is in high frequency and the other factors occur all together only 2 times or less:

My example matrix is:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "Y", "M", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "X", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "G"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))
```

The desired output:

```
structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "Y", "M", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "F", "F", "F", "F"), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8"), NULL))

   [,1] [,2]
r1 "M"  "M" 
r2 "M"  "Y" 
r3 "M"  "Y" 
r4 "M"  "Y" 
r5 "M"  "F" 
r6 "Y"  "F" 
r7 "Y"  "F" 
r8 "Y"  "F"
```

So I would like to delete column 3, 4, 5 and 6 since all factors which are not the major factor occur in frequency one or two.

At the moment I have this:

```
my_fun2 <- function(x) {
  vec <- factor(x, levels = unique(x))
  lapply(vec, 
         function(y) ifelse(y, 
                     
}

n.mat[] <- n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, my_fun2]
```

Comment: Yes your right, sorry, I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a column-wise `apply` on your matrix.

In each step, count the different letters (using `table`), sort the resulting numbers from highest to lowest (using `sort`) and check if the second entry is less than two or not.

```
n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[2] >= 3)]

   [,1] [,2]
r1 "M"  "M" 
r2 "M"  "Y" 
r3 "M"  "Y" 
r4 "M"  "Y" 
r5 "M"  "F" 
r6 "Y"  "F" 
r7 "Y"  "F" 
r8 "Y"  "F"
```